# Cancel Gmail Meter Apps Script trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Two years ago I installed the Gmail Meter on my G-mail account. It provides me reports monthly. Since I'm not aware about managing the triggers and this stuff, I have no idea how and where I could stop or cancel that trigger.
Can you give me a clue?

Comment: Dear All,
I followed Sandy's advice, revoking access ... Mayy you give me some next clue, how I could get rid of these messages:

"Your script, Gmail Meter, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here."
There must be something next to be deleted. probably.
Thank you,
PJ

Answer (score 3):

You can see all your triggers by opening up the script editor.  Do you have any Apps Script files in your Drive?

[Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/)

If you do, open up an Apps Script, and in the script editor, choose the **RESOURCES** menu, and the **ALL YOUR TRIGGERS** menu item.  You can review, and delete all your triggers there.

The Gmail Meter documentation states that you received an email when you signed up, and that email has a link to uninstall the app.  Did you go through that process?

Also, go into your Google Account,

[Link To Google Settings Page](https://www.google.com/settings/account)

and view all your connected apps.

[image: Connected Apps]

Revoke Access to any App that you don't want any more.

Also go into your security checkup:

[image: Security Checkup]

and remove anything that you don't want anymore.

The Gmail Meter documentation also states:

> Lastly, simply delete the file in your Google Docs/Drive that is used for storing the Gmail Meter data: "Gmail Meter Data - Do not delete".

Comment: Dear Sandy,
Thank you very much for your quick answer.
I didn't find any script on my Google Docs Drive, nevertheless I utilized your next two hints (your links were helpful also). I didn't find the "Gmail Meter Data - Do not delete" file btw.
Thank you again.
PJ

Answer (score 1):

Try signing up to the platform again here http://www.gmailmeter.com/#sthash.YeNkVmQn.dpbs and then cancel the script through the official link when the confirmation mail arrives [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grQFT.png).

Answer (score 0):

Go to account.google.com
Then log  in using your Google Account.
Now scroll down to find the "Account Permissions" and select it.
Now find the Gmail Meter, select it and choose Revoke Access from the top right corner.